# Incoming call dynamically override default ringtone

Tags: android, ringtone

My app allows you to specify a different ringtone for different incoming events. EG: incoming call, incoming SMS, etc.

What I am trying to accomplish is when I receive for example an incoming call, I check my apps database if a specific option is selected and if there is a ringtone option set play that ringtone.

However the problem I am having is I am unable to override / stop the default phone ringtone from playing.

I have tried several different ways, but from the docs most of those methods only stop the current instance and are not global methods.

I can't set the ringtone in the default phones ringtone settings as it needs to be dynamic based on the incoming call.

If anyone knows of a trick or a way to accomplish this that would be great.
I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 12):

There are a several steps to dynamically change the ringtone.

### 1. Prepare ringtone

```
    File k = new File("/sdcard/ringtone", "kolyan_.mp3");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Some Artist");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
```

### 2. Insert it into the database

```
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
    // Line below is major because we need to delete old entry
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    mUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

### 3. Save the current default ringtone and subscribe to CallListener

```
    // Be careful by calling getActualDefaultRingtoneUri in CallListener, it could return null, better way to save it in OnCreate
    mOldUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mTelephonyMgr.listen(new MyCallListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

### 4. Create MyCallListener class

```
class MyCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // On call you replace the ringtone with your own mUri
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                        mUri
                );
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                // Restore the default ringtone
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                        mOldUri
                );
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
}
```

### 5. Add permissions to you AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

### 6. Done

The main idea is hooking for incoming call and replace the ringtone by your own. And of course you should restore default ringtone to saved value after call.

Comment: Somehow for me, even tough the ringtone is effectively replaced it still play the old one... any clue?

Comment: Not enough information to figure out. 
Try look at logs. Try to check return value of getActualDefaultRingtoneUri after you set it.

Comment: I did (getActualDefaultRingtoneUri) and the value is correct and it  will be the default if I don't revert it back at CALL_STATE_IDLE. It seems as if the system acquire the Ringtone Uri to play before I change it.

Comment: I'm still asked to include `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Answer (score 4):

Starting with API 5 (Android 2.x), the Contacts database has a CUSTOM_RINGTONE field, see this page:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.html#CUSTOM_RINGTONE

The value for this field must be a `content://` URI to a media file.  You can obtain one from the `MedciaStore` content provider:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html

That may be enough to get you started.  This is all standard content provider stuff; lots of existing material for both tasks.