# Android:Incoming call:How to play my ringtone instead of the native one?

Tags: android

At incoming call is it possible to play my defined ringtone instead of the default one which is set for the device?

Thank you.

Comment: this might help you 




[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182891/how-can-i-change-the-ringtone-in-android-programmatically][2]


 [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity][3]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182891/how-can-i-change-the-ringtone-in-android-programmatically
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182891/how-can-i-change-the-ringtone-in-android-programmatically
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incoming call dynamically override default ringtone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387556/incoming-call-dynamically-override-default-ringtone)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

I have followed following link to set and reset Ringtone:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity

But here I have to reset it again with the default ringtone which was set. Beause my rintone should be played only if my application is in foreground.

Is there any other way to play ringtone by overriding default one?